# What is this slope called?

Tags: word-request

It’s in front of the house and in the middle of sidewalk.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest "ramp". You can better describe it as "sidewalk ramp" or "house driveway ramp". Since it looks like it was built for cars to park in front of the house, even though it is used as a shop. (For US English)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curb_cut) it is called "curb cut (U.S.), curb ramp, dropped kerb (UK), pram ramp, or kerb ramp (Australia)".

Comment: I think _access ramp_ would work in the US, too.

Comment: Come to think of it, the thingy in the picture may be an access ramp (for the shop) and not the usual "curb cut" the Wikipedia article is about. I assumed the OP was asking about the more common pedestrian ramp.

Comment: Does it matter? They all seem to be pretty much the same thing either way.